# How to Execute SQL Query in ASP.NET MVC, and Pass to a View

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I need to execute this SQL and pass the resulting data as a model to a View. How can I do this?

```
string query = 
"SELECT alum.IdAlumno, Nombres + ' ' +
        alum.Apellido1 + ' ' + 
        alum.Apellido2 as Nombre 
 FROM dbo.Alumnos AS alum 
 JOIN dbo.SolicitudCurso AS Soli ON alum.IdAlumno = Soli.IdAlumno 
 JOIN dbo.Cursos AS cur ON cur.IdCurso = Soli.IdCurso
 WHERE cur.IdCurso = " + id.ToString();
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is generally considered too broad to properly answer in this forum.

You really need to invest some time to work through some tutorials, and then adapt the learning to your specific situation.

This looks like a good tutorial to start with: https://www.guru99.com/insert-update-delete-asp-net.html

Good luck!